# Unable to connect two databases in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-oracledb

I´m having a issue when using 2 DB's at same time (both oracle).
My `startup` function only execute first connection try catch block, but show console.log connection message of second try catch block, but the connection is never made.

Here's my `startup` function:

```
async function startup() {
  try {
    console.log('Initializing SEI database module...');
    await seiDatabase.initialize();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    process.exit(1); // Non-zero failure code
  }
  console.log('Starting SEI application...');

  try {
    console.log('Initializing SIP database module...');
    await sipDatabase.initialize();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    process.exit(1); // Non-zero failure code
  }
  console.log('Starting SIP application...');

  try {
    console.log('Initializing web server module...');
    await webServer.initialize();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);

    process.exit(1); // Non-zero failure code
  }
}
startup();
```

I´m using the same `webServer.initialize` for both...
When I try to use my SIP route to get data, this error is returned: `message    "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist"`, my route is trying to get data from SIP DB, but only SEI DB is connected...
I'm doing the multiple connection in the wrong way?

Im using Node, Express and oracledb ^5.4.0"... not using any TypeORM.

Comment: How do you know that `only SEI DB is connected`? If this is the error **ORA-00942** you got after querying in SIP DB, it means you're connected to SIP DB.

Comment: @RahulSharma I've changed try catch positions and let SIP DB connect first and my query start working... and my SEI DB (previousily first connection) stop working. Here's a little console message:
`Initializing SEI database module...
Starting SEI application...
Initializing SIP database module...
Starting SIP application...
Initializing web server module...
Web server listening on localhost:4242`  
Looks like my query is trying to get data from SEI DB...

Comment: Make sure you have the correct variable scope, otherwise you might be overwriting the variable holding the connection (or pool?) of the first DB with a connection (or pool) for the second DB.  If you are using two pools, make sure to assign and then use a pool alias name (or pass around the pool object).    Check the doc https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#connpoolcache.

Comment: @ChristopherJones that worked just fine! I've added a poolAlias in each hrPool connection and called the alias in connection... `conn = await oracledb.getConnection('sipprod');` and `conn = await oracledb.getConnection('seiprod');`
Please, make a Answer for solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using two pools, make sure to assign and then use a pool alias name (or pass around the pool object). Check the doc [Connection Pool Cache](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#connpoolcache).

For example, two pools could be created like:

```
await oracledb.createPool({
  user: 'hr',
  password: myhrpw, 
  connectString: 'localhost/XEPDB1',
  poolAlias: 'hrpool'
});

await oracledb.createPool({
  user: 'sh',
  password: myshpw,
  connectString: 'localhost/XEPDB1',
  poolAlias: 'shpool'
});
```

Then you would get a connection from the desired pool by specifying its alias.  For example:

```
const connection = await oracledb.getConnection('hrpool');

. . . // Use connection from the HR pool

await connection.close();
```

Comment: Thanks, passing explicity what pool I need solved the problem, using `oracledb.getConnection();` was letting my connection only on first pool and not letting second one get connected!